# php - Execute if all the array values are <= 0

Tags: php, arrays

```
$result = Array ( 
[0] => Array ( [qty_received] => 1 ) 
[1] => Array ( [qty_received] => 12 ) 
[2] => Array ( [qty_received] => 1 ) 
[3] => Array ( [qty_received] => 0 ) 
[4] => Array ( [qty_received] => -1 ) 
)
```

I'm trying to run an update query when all the `qty_received` values of the array is less than or equal to zero(<=0), else stop the execution.

We can stop the execution if any of the value is >0. Need to run the update query only if all the values in the $result is <=0.

I tried with the below code, but not working as expected. Thanks in advance.

```
foreach ($result as $qty_received) {
    if ($qty_received > 0){                
        break;
    }else{
        $this->db->update($this->table, $data);
    }
}
```

Comment: In your else statement you've commented 'update query'. According to your information that should happen outside of the loop.

Comment: Your comparison is invalid, because you compare an entire array to a number.

Comment: It's not about *where*, it's about *how*.

Comment: this is true...
foreach ($result as $item) {
    if ($item['qty_received'] > 0){                
        break;
    }else{
        $this->db->update($this->table, $data);
    }
}

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I just though of [max](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.max.php), combined with [array_column](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php):

```
// Find the highest value in the array, see if its lower than zero
$isFullyNegative = 0 >= max(array_column($array, 'qty_received'));
```

---

One way could be array_filter:

```
// take only the negatives, if the number of elements is the same as the
// the original one its fully negative 
$negatives = array_filter($array, function($value){ return $value <=0; });
$fullyNegative = count($array) === count($negatives);
```

You could also make a lightweight helper function, this could be more lightweight because it stops when it finds a positive:

```
function isFullyNegative(array $values): bool {
    foreach($values as $value){
        if($value > 0 ){
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

And of course you can take the other examples and make a function of them for usability too

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Should I add the update query inside the if condition?

Comment: No. Its like this: `if( isFullyNegative($array) ){ /** do update stuff **/ }`. No else, if that function returns true they're all good.

Comment: Tiny detail: shouldn't it be `0 >= max`, since the spec is "0 or less"?

Comment: FYI: we prefer not to get "thank you' responses, the accept will do :) This to minimize noise

Comment: Side notes: not really sure what should happen when `$array` is empty (or whether it can actually happen in OPs case). `max(array_column($array, 'qty_received'))` would throw an exception. `$fullyNegative = count($array) === count($negatives);` would be true in case `$array === []`. `isFullyNegative([])` would also return true.

Answer (score 1):

Your have array of arrays and the array inside is assoc. Try:

```
$update = true;
foreach ($result as $assoc) {
    if ($assoc['qty_received'] > 0) {                
        $update = false;
        break;
    }
}
if($update) { //update }
```

or as far as you have only 1 key in your array, you could use this, otherwise this couldn't work like you want. For more info see comments under this post.

```
if(max($result)['qty_received'] < 0) {
   // update
}
```

Comment: This will still execute the update even if not all values are 0 or less if the first value satisfied the condition.

Comment: Actually. I did not understand the question. I corrected the post

Comment: That is not how max() works :) See http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/161b2fc89d47111ec8a04f84077cf5657e882a83

Comment: @Martijn but you have two keys, see with one.

Comment: Hm, so it works because of some weird internal logic. I would not recommend doing it this way. This is the kind of 'magic' that disappears on a PHP update (and then you'd get something "expected only integers, got ..."). This solution will fail as soon as another column is selected before this. Very unstable :)

Comment: Ok, your point. It can be confusing so I edited post.

Comment: Maybe better to use `array_values`, it would be somewhat more predictabl

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?:

```
$has_value_over_zero= false;
foreach ($result as $res)
{
    if ($res['qty_received'] > 0){
      $has_value_over_zero= true;break;
    }
}

if (!$has_value_over_zero)
{
    $this->db->update($this->table, $data);
  echo "update";
}
else {
  echo "Some of the values are over 0, no update";
}
```